# How to pass local file file to webview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to display .pptx file in flutter and i find this code. i replace yourlink with path like 'storage/emulated/0/faaz.pptx'. but still not working any help please

```
var yourLink = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';

WebView(
initialUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$yourLink', 
);
if your file is from local replace yourLink with localPath.
```